# Android. Java. Adapter. Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, adapter

Есть фрагмент. В нём с сервера в методе `onViewCreated()` подгружаю историю сообщений между 2-мя пользователями

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  //....
    new Thread(()-> {
        try {
            Observable.fromArray(api.getMessages("sender", "recipient"))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(message -> {
                        addMessage(message);
                    });
         } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Упс! Что-то пошло не так!", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

**Проблема:**

При старте фрагмента, сообщения полученные с сервера не отображаются, при том, что запрос на сервер уже был сделан и был получен ответ. Выглядит это так:
[image: Старт фрагмента]

Но как только я дотрагиваюсь именно до `EditText (Ваше сообщение)` 
Мои сообщения тут же появляются. Выглядит это так:

[image: Результат]

Как можно исправить, чтобы сообщения показывались при старте фрагмента?

Comment: Возможно вы тут хотели `observeOn` написать и проблема в этом? `.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб К сожалению, результат такой же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте тогда программно открыть клавиатуру по завершению работы обсервера.

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doOnComplete(() -> {
    showInputMethod();
})
.subscribe(message -> {
  addMessage(message);
});


public void showInputMethod() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
           Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
           InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
```